# Downloading multiple pdf files using Spring Boot RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to use a Spring Boot RestController to download multiple pdf files.But for some reason only the first file is downloaded.The program does not throw any error.Not sure what the issue is.Is Multipart needed for this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "downloadAgain", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void newRun(HttpServletResponse response) {

        String fileName1="pdf1.pdf";
        String fullName1="C://Users//pdf1.pdf";
        newDownloadRun(response,fileName1,fullName1);

        String fileName2="pdf2.pdf";
        String fullName2="C://Users//pdf2.pdf";
        newDownloadRun(response,fileName2,fullName2);
    }


    public void newDownloadRun(HttpServletResponse response,String fileName,String fullName) {

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ fileName );

        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

        try {
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fullName);
            int len;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            while((len=fis.read(buf))> 0) {
                bos.write(buf,0,len);
            }
            bos.close();
            response.flushBuffer();
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Http protocol designed to send one file per request. if you want to send multiple files you need to prepare it as multipart/related. Look into this article https://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_multiple-files-one-request/

Comment: Thanks Ravi.Will look into it.

Comment: The examples I see of MultipartFile that I see are more to do with uploading multiple files to a server.Can the same be done to downloading files to the local directory ?